# Inject variables environment after build

Tags: typescript, npm, build

Let's see if anyone can enlighten me

I have been doing some research, and I found some library that inject after build but that's not what I want.
What I want is to build the project and then inject the environment of staging or production. So basically I want to build just one time and inject then any file of environment(staging or production) after.
Now I'm using webpack where I have the Dotenv library and if I want to use staging or production environment I have to build two times.

Is that possible?
Thanks[image: build]

Comment: Are you talking about client-side code or server-side code? If server-side, my experience of the `dotenv` library is that you can set environment variables at runtime to control whether you're using staging information or production information (or dev/debug).

Comment: server-side, okey, what I would like is to make a staging build and in case it works inject the production variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've said that this is for server-side code and that you're using `dotenv`.

You don't need to rebuild for production. There are at least a couple of approaches you can take:

1. Use environment variables rather than `dotenv`, or
2. Use environment variables to control what `.env.xyz` file `dotenv` loads, or
3. Both.

I suggest #1.

### 1. Use environment variables (without `dotenv`)

You can just use environment variables without using `dotenv`. (This is how most of my projects are done.) `dotenv` cites the [Twelve-Factor App](https://12factor.net/config) guidelines while simultaneously encouraging you to break them — by having a `.env` file, which is a config file. The guidelines frown on using config files for environment information; from the link:

> The twelve-factor app stores config in *environment variables* (often shortened to env vars or env). Env vars are easy to change between deploys without changing any code; unlike config files, there is little chance of them being checked into the code repo accidentally...

(I'm not saying the Twelve-Factor App guidelines are gospel, just that it seems odd to cite them while encouraging using a config file.) I *think* the idea of `dotenv` is that you don't ever check `.env` into source control, but create it manually in the root of each of your environments. But that's not how I see it used in the wild.

So instead, of `dotenv`, you could do what those guidelines suggest: Use environment variables. Your hosting platform will provide a way to set environment variables for the environment your code runs in. Those variables will be available on [`process.env`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processenv), no need for `dotenv`.

Here's a simple example:

`index.js`:

```js
console.log(process.env.EXAMPLE);
```

If you run that in an environment with an `EXAMPLE` environment variable, you'll see that variable's value in the console. So you use the features of your hosting platform to set your environment variables, and you're all set.

(If you want to just try that out locally, you can do it like this on *nix:

```sh
$ EXAMPLE=hi node index.js
hi
```

...or like this on Windows:

```
C:\Temp> cmd /C "set EXAMPLE=hi && node index.js"
hi
```

...but don't get the wrong impression from that. You don't set the environment variables at the command line, you set them in whatever way your hosting platform makes available to you.)

### 2. Using environment variables (with `dotenv`)

If you want to use `dotenv` and have config files, though, you can use an environment variable to control what config file gets loaded. (This is how a couple of projects I work with are done.)

You might set an environment variable telling your code what environment it's running in (dev, staging, production, etc.), and then use that to tell `dotenv` what `.env.xyz` file to load. `create-react-app` has made `NODE_ENV` popular, for instance, using `NODE_ENV=DEV` for dev and `NODE_ENV=PROD` for production. You might use that to control `dotenv`, telling it to use `.env.PROD` for production but (say) `.env.DEV` for development or `.env.STAGING` for staging, etc.

```js
import path from "path";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV ?? "DEV";
dotenv.config({
    path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), `.env.${env}`),
});
```

### 3. Both

You can do a combination of the above. `dotenv` won't overwrite something in `process.env` if it's already there (because it's set in the environment). So you could have information in an `.env` file and override it using the environment features of your hosting platform. But that seems unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Thank you so much @t-j-crowder! Im considering the second option, but I have a dummy question, If I want to change from staging to production what file in the .tmp(pckg) I have to change to use the variables from production? Thanks

Comment: @Lluis - None. With Option 2 you set an environment variable to tell your code which environment it's running in, and have `dotenv` pick up the relevant environment file (which is present in the package).